# Convert PySpark dataframe column a list/array entries to double list/array entries

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like convert a Pyspark dataframe having the following schema structure.

```
root
 |-- top: long (nullable = true)
 |-- inner: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- inner1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- inner2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- inner3: date (nullable = true)
 |    |-- inner4: date (nullable = true)
```

to:

```
root
 |-- top: long (nullable = true)
 |-- inner: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- inner1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inner2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inner3: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inner4: date (nullable = true)
```

This is basically changing

```
top | [ inner1, inner2, inner3, inner4]
```

to

```
top | [[inner1, inner2, inner3, inner4]]
```

Comment: So you want to convert `struct` to `array`?

Comment: The result should be exactly as shown above when you run df.printSchema() after conversion. The field 'element' is I think automatically inferred when you have list of lists. It looks like the struct is actually nested inside an array.